# GeoPandas legend not displaying correctly the colors

Tags: python, geopandas

I need a legend where for every bin that I defined there is a color from a colorscale.

I wrote this:

```
ax= merge.plot(column=dates,
               figsize=[15,15], 
               cmap='OrRd', 
               scheme='user_defined', 
               classification_kwds={'bins':[10,20,50,100,200,500,1000]},
               legend=True
               )
```

and I keep getting this:

[image: Legend]

As you can see the first three colours are white and the last three are dark red.

How can I modify my code to get a shade of colour for a single bin?

Here's an example of what I would like it to be:

[image: Preferred Legend]

Comment: Have you tried adding all the desired break points in your code?

Comment: Can you explain further your question? I added the desired size of the bins in the "classification_kwds" parameter...

Comment: Your target example has three more classes.

Comment: I tried as you suggested more bins and there weren't any changes. I tried with more bins than the example but nothing changed.

If it helps, i uploaded my entire code on [Github](https://github.com/giorgiosala/Python-exercises/blob/master/London%20Covid%20Cases/london.py)